# How to deploy K8 apps in k8 Cluster through Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

I tried to use the Kubernetes Continuous Deploy Plugin but its seem it ran on the slave and deploy the app, but I want to deploy K8 Apps in K8 cluster not in jenkins slave.

Answer (score 0):

As it described at [wiki-pages](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Continuous+Deploy+Plugin) you need configure access to your kubernetes cluster.

From documentation:

> In the "Kubeconfig" dropdown, select the > [kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/authenticate-across-clusters-kubeconfig/) stored in Jenkins.

in `kubeconfig` you store the access to your cluster, without this it would not work.